# JTDS connect to remote server fail

Tags: android, sql, jtds

don't know why, the app when connecting to the SQL Server that is on the same network as the device, I can connect to it without any problems, but now I need to connect from the device over the internet to the SQL Server, isn't working, don't know why. I have a button to test the connection and it will call a method that contains this, the method is on background (AsyncTaskRunner)

```
try
{
    String host, port, dbname, user, password, instance;
    host = _editTextHost.getText().toString();
    port = _editTextPort.getText().toString();
    instance = _editTextInstance.getText().toString();
    dbname = _editTextDbName.getText().toString();
    user = _editTextUser.getText().toString();
    password = _editTextPass.getText().toString();
    String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String conString;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(port))
    {
        conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + ";databaseName=" + dbname + ";instance=" + instance;
    }
    else
    {
        conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + dbname + ";instance=" + instance;
    }
    Connection con;
    Class.forName(driver);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, user, password);
    con.close();
    conSuccess = true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("SQLConfig", "Fail to connect");
    Log.e("SQLConfig", e.toString());
    Log.e("SQLConfig", e.getMessage());
}
return null;
```

When I do try to connect to the SQL Server on the same network works without any problems, but when I activate the 4g on the device I allways get the same error, that it can't find the instance. But if I connect to the server through the "SQL Server Management Studio" using the same information I can connect to the server without any problems.

I'm using the jtds driver, 1.3.1.

What could be doing this? Thanks

P.S. I all rdy have read some stuff about webservice, but I want to remove this option for now out of the picture

Edit 1: To clarify, I can connect to the server using the credentials on the version of Windows CE of the program or SQL Server Management Studio. When I put the outside IP and all the require information it connects to the server, it not connect on the Android only

Comment: Networking basics: [Private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) ... obviously on 4g you are in different network, so without some obvious solution like public ip on server or some NAT solution you cannot connect to server ... but obviously making SQL server world-visible is terrible mistake

Comment: I know that, thats why I have done the port forward and such, thats why I have told if I use the credentials (outside IP aka internet IP that is static and such) on the SQL Server Management Studio or on the the program that I have done for Windows CE (There is a version for Android and another for Windows CE) it does connect to the server, but on Android it doesnt. Saying this, thats the reason to reach out the community here, to see if there was something wrong with the code or could be something on the jtds driver and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well by changing the conString  a little I was able to connect without any problems either from the localnetwork or the internet.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(port))
{
    conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + ";databaseName=" + dbname + ";instance=" + instance;
}
else
{
    conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + dbname + ";instance=" + instance;
}
```

To

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(port))
{
    conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + "/" + instance + ";DatabaseName=" +dbname;
}
else
{
    conString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + instance + ";DatabaseName=" + dbname;
}
```

Now works without any problems either using the public host or the localnetwork to access the db.